# Typescript generic conditional does not precise the type

Tags: typescript, if-statement, generics

Here is a piece of code ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEwPYDUCGAbArtAvFA3gFBRSIB2EAXFGZgLYBGEATgNzFTADui1AzsGYBLMgHN2AX3YAzTGQDGwIeSgBZEADE5i5WQA8MKBAAewCGQAmfKAGsIIRNNjwkaLBAB8ACg4A3DNjUcJCuARAA2jAAugA0HKCQQXEAlAQcQk5eCbg4eADk5BB5qcwQwJjMZFD%207gB0wIgaQsYQFl4ATMnsJBlQWfBQufnciMVQpeWV1WH1iADKgiKiXsnxABbMiFxQAKLMm8xeeSI1Qhac8MWEEkA), Typescript 5.0.4) that takes a generic function, and do some operation depending on the type:

```js
type TypeToValue = {
  one: number;
  two: string;
};
function MyFunction<T extends keyof TypeToValue>(
  value: TypeToValue[T],
  type: T,
) {
  if (type === 'one') return value.toFixed(2); // fail "Property 'toFixed' does not exist on type 'string | number'."
  if (type === 'two') return value.toString()
  throw Error('invalid type')
}
```

However, I expect it not to fail because Typescript should be aware that after `type === 'one'`, then the generic `T` is `'one'` hence value is typed as `number`.

Is there a workaround to have the type automatically inferred?

Thanks !

Comment: Please [edit] your post to ask a single primary question. If the primary question is "is my reasoning correct" then the answer is "not exactly; it's possible for `T` to be the full union as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/mLvdZw), leading to runtime errors. There's a feature request at [ms/TS#27808](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808) to prevent that and have it work the way you expect". If it's "is there a workaround" then you can use a rest param of a discriminated union type as shown [here](//tsplay.dev/WKvlMm). I'm happy to flesh one of those out into an answer post. Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @jcalz for providing a valid workaround ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKuEwPYDUCGAbArtAvFA3gFBRSIB2EAXFGZgLYBGEATgNzFTADui1AzsGYBLMgHN2AX3aFCoSFACyIAGKYyAY2BDyAQWai%20UPPigBtANJQRUANYQQiAGax4SNFggBdaqYBuGbGo4SDcAiAtPABpOeGpzTygJUzsHZ2CEFDDPGUc1TW0yRRU8rXIACgA6Kr8w6LkvaiVVDVKyPQMASgIOIWcy%20qMcPABycghhruYIYExmQv8PCuBEZSEADwgAEzKAJg7WKAB6Q9IbVBAevoGhke5ECagpmbmoBewlxABlQRFRMo6OMAABbMRBcKAAUWYoOYZWGIgWQk2MUgE0IEhkQA)):

```js
type TypeToValue = {
  one: number;
  two: string;
};


type MyFunctionArgs = { [K in keyof TypeToValue]: [value: TypeToValue[K], type: K] }[keyof TypeToValue]

function MyFunction(...[value, type]: MyFunctionArgs) {
  if (type === 'one') return value.toFixed(2); // okay
  if (type === 'two') return value.toString()
  throw Error('invalid type')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the inference is not smart enough to understand the proper type. However, that's just my humble opinion.

Anyway, here is a slightly different version, where it simply evaluates the type at runtime. That also ensures the proper inference.

```
type TypeToValue = {
  one: number;
  two: string;
};
function MyFunction<T extends keyof TypeToValue>(
  value: TypeToValue[T],
  //  type: T,
) {
  if (typeof value === 'number') return value.toFixed(2);
  if (typeof value === 'string') return value.toString()
  throw Error('invalid type')
}

let s: string;
s = MyFunction<"one">(123.456);
console.log(s);    //prints "123.46" 

s = MyFunction<"two">("hello");
console.log(s);    //prints "hello"
```

Also no need of the second argument.

Comment: Thank you, it's a great way but my actual case is more complex where `number` and `string` are objects. Moreover the value of `TypeToValue` might overlap.

Answer (score 0):

You need something more generic for your task. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQElK0SgjKgb2AEgEAuVAZwhnAHMBuEgIwrAFcBbZ2JgX2Cgs8ZGkzQRKAEyESSCswD2igDZQEYJsQAmFDQE9+g8BJxjhZgMyziUBcrUatu1AaOC47MEgghFYVBBKcWxRAB4AFQA+AAoANwQVdjtXMH0ASgoEpLQg1AibEDhUGIh9AAcoRWLs5NQAQgBeRtQAckVmACsoH1bUAB9+1Fq0ZpaOFRV0m2IYKAh2GADEFUooLQFiOEUYEqR-alQAayh9QICR6aJiYiKSkYBtE-0AXVQx1C9tKDhwKG0riQbnMFktUCs1lpiJtNiDFgEaMkjGVKvkKlAIooAGqJOrjLg8XZDai0MB0AYYCyifBDEKSKAyWlUlCWJgeLw+PwBACy+gAYhzfP5ShQIujMTicoDbsVSujqqgIO9mqgAEQcbiwVXS2bzeGKgB0EEUfJAAA9-jEpOkNoIZSUUVVikqPqqSfRtTM4WCIEbFABlGj0GI2kgCEh3GJBOlmMIx6mxCDpHX7MCUVRQA0qRR0GKtcowRQoSiUeioDqdcvO9GU0zU1qh4F6n0MVAAejb5d22kUVEUnHmAAsywB3EAQQflro9JUKx210J4MN2yPR5lQOPrqSJ5MzVPptRZnN5gtFqAlssVquKmvxvANqHehGtjtd1A9vsDiej8eTisz695zvBllwjWU1zrFBN0gqBLB3FMDgzI9c3zQti1LMkp0rOdb3XSwHyBJ9FRfTsdnfXt0y-YdMLHCcsIAnDUWAqRQOICdCxHVAwCgTiAFEYELGAYlVTBshAbQb0qbV3FfaBqGAfdZy6fAWgIVwKFaQcoEmRRWgAGlQVhUFwAAGEzUD4JhFKwmRVNQeRFRgZIDJcVoRx2FRtD6SyFIOJTOmsOyUlVREoFVFyNPcmBPO8qzEMPbNc15AVvCFMAYlMkzkzitMkMSmJksFLlhP8NBBw0bQ5m0bVQ33PLj0K1LiorXBst83KEoa-kiuFCtrVDV86s6pLuqa3quksNqgA)

```
interface Interface1 {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

interface Interface2 {
    c: boolean;
    d: any;
}

function isInterface<T>(value: any): value is T {
    if (typeof value !== 'object' || value === null) {
        return false;
    }
    for (const key in value) {
        if (value[key] === undefined) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

type TypeToValue = number | string | Interface1 | Interface2;    

function MyFunction(t: TypeToValue) {
    if (typeof t === "number") {
        return t.toFixed(2);
    }

    if (typeof t === "string") {
        return t.toString();
    }

    if (isInterface<Interface1>(t)) {
        console.log('processing obj of type Interface1');
        return t; // or do something with object of type Interface1
    }

    if (isInterface<Interface2>(t)) {
        console.log('processing obj of type Interface2');
        return t; // or do something with object of type Interface2
    }

    throw new Error("Invalid type");
}

// test
const obj1 = { a: 'hello', b: 100 };
const obj2 = { c: true, d: 'world' };
console.log(MyFunction(100));
console.log(MyFunction("one hundred"));
console.log(MyFunction(obj1));
console.log(MyFunction(obj2));
```

Comment: that works only when the types have different field names, not optional, nor with different type. For instance, in `Interface1` you have `a:string` and `Interface2` you have `a:number`. Even worse if you have `a:Interface3` on both `Interface1` and `Interface2`. As "interface" it applies to a variety of concrete objects. Not a good solution to me.